# Java "Syntax Error on token ";", { expected after this token" error

Tags: java, syntax

I am stuck on an error I keep getting, I have isolated the area the error has developed but cant figure out the cause.

```
package guiProject;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.File;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.nio.file.Paths;
import java.nio.file.Path;
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;

import java.awt.EventQueue;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import java.awt.CardLayout;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import java.awt.Font;
import javax.swing.JTextField;
import javax.swing.JPasswordField;
import java.awt.event.MouseAdapter;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import javax.swing.JTree;

public class mainWindow {

    // imports and class definition are before this point
    private Path adminList = 
    Paths.get("src/guiProject/AdminList.txt").toAbsolutePath();

    try {
        List<String> admins = Files.lines(adminList).collect(Collectors.toList());
    } catch (IOException e) {

    }
// rest of code
```

The error is occurring at the end of the line that defines adminList. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Is this inside of a method?

Comment: `private` is for class members. Surely it can't be at the same level as the `try` statement. Check where your code is written.

Comment: Is the variable definition in a method, or is the try-catch block outside one?  You need to show the enclosing code.

Comment: Please provide more context with the problematic code to help you. Is this inside a method or not? You may paste the relevant part of the class code here, obviously removing any confidential information.

Comment: Sorry about the confusion, I have updated the post to have all code before the error point. If someone needs me to post the entirety of the code please let me know and I will, there is nothing confidential.

Comment: Your code needs to be inside a method (a function). Right now the code is at class level.

Comment: Thanks for the help, it did need to be in a method.

Answer (score 0):

Put your code inside a method - say `pullAdminList` . Moreover `private` access of `adminList` works just fine, because, again your methods -  member of class, can access it:

```
   public List<String> pullAdminList()
   {
     List<String> admins;
     try 
     {
         admins = Files.lines(adminList).collect(Collectors.toList());
     } 
     catch (IOException e) {
     }
     return admins;
   }
```